# Up to date http server implementation/tutorial using netty and java

Tags: java, netty

I am trying to use the netty example of an http server located [here](http://goo.gl/MG4Afl). I am using netty ver 4.0.29.Final. In the HttpServerHandler class which extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler it overrides

```
messageReceived(ChannelContextHandler ctx, Object msg)
```

I get the following two errors:

1. The method messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext, Object) of type HttpServerHandler must override or implement a supertype method
2. There is no HttpHeaderUtil in the io.netty.handler.codec.http package.

I am guessing there are changes and the tutorial is not up to date. Do you have any idea what can I use instead?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the sources for the 4.0.x version. Your link leads to 5.x examples.

http://netty.io/4.0/xref/

or the equivalent to your link:

http://netty.io/4.0/xref/io/netty/example/http/snoop/package-summary.html

the method is called:

```
protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {

}
```